# Using a test Pairwise Wilcoxon in Python like in R

Tags: python

I have a simple question that I couldn't find on internet. 
How to perform a pairwise wilcoxon and obtain a nice table of comparaison between the groups in Python?
I know with R the test is pairwise.wilcox.test().

An example:

[image]

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you give an example ? For those like me that just don't know about this

Comment: @SyntaxVoidsupportsMonica. I've already did that but it doesn't answer to my question. There is no table at the end with the different groups. Only the p-value result

Comment: @azro Tell me if you need another example :)